# Java memory leak vs heap dump information

Tags: java, memory-leaks, heap-memory

We're running against an issue related with memory.

Our monitor is saying that out service is consuming 800MiB of memory.

We've created a heap dump. However, this heap dump is telling us that total heap size is 41MiB.

[image]

Out service is running inside a container. We've read a lot some issue related with java and docker containers. However, we're trying to get some more information.

How could we otain more memory related information about java vm?

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the `monitor` you referring to?

Comment: It's a monitor provided by an external provider... Data is recolected and shown on a grafana dashboard...

Comment: The most obvious question is, looking at the classes in heap dump - do the distributions look like you application should? Also you can try to connect with profiler directly to application and try to see it live.

Comment: Maybe you can add some more details about this external provider? From a naive point of view it might just be that this provider is not able to accurately collect the informations. Also if you monitor the data yourself (from inside the container) does this data match to what your monitor is telling you?

Answer (score 1):

The big discrepancy between the memory usage reported by the heap dump and the usage reported by external monitoring could be due to a few things.  Some things to look at include:

1. A JVM's memory utilization does not just consist of the Java heap.  It includes the JVM executable and shared libraries, metaspace, the native (malloc) heap and memory segments that hold thread stacks.  It potentially also includes memory mapped files, and memory segments shared with other processes.
2. The memory used by the Java heap includes objects that are unreachable, and space that isn't currently allocated to objects; i.e. free heap space.

How can you get more information about Java memory utilization?

A primary source is ["Java Platform, Standard Edition Troubleshooting Guide"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/):

- The [Native Memory Tracking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html) section explains how to use `jcmd` to get an overall picture.
- The [JFR Memory Tab](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr005.html#BABHFCDD) provides live monitoring of Java Heap usage stats and the GC.
- The [Jmap Utility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr014.html#BABGAFEG) can be used to obtain heap and GC configuration information, heap histograms and classloader stats.
- GC logging can give useful insights into GC behavior.